# The limit of ulimit -Hn

Tags: linux, ulimit

Using trial and error, I've found the maximum number I can give to `ulimit -Hn` without getting error is `1048576`. Where does that number come from? My `sys.fs.file-max` is `20000500` (20 million).

Comment: Have you checked /etc/security/limits.conf ?

Comment: ... and also /etc/security/limits.d/ which is essenstially a pluggable variant of limits.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this limit can be increased. Set `fs.nr_open=5242880`
in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, run `sysctl -p` and login again. Your limit is now
5 million! Set both this and file-max.

Comment: doesn't work on Amazon linux, at least. I also needed this: http://serverfault.com/a/702074/58945

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is hardcoded in Linux kernel, in [`fs/file.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/file.c#L26):

```
int sysctl_nr_open __read_mostly = 1024*1024;
```

and is equal to just the number you specified.

Related commits that tried to make it infinite:

- https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=0c2d64fb6cae9aae480f6a46cfe79f8d7d48b59f
- https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=60fd760fb9ff7034360bab7137c917c0330628c2

Looks like it hasn't been touched ever since.